# Calculator button no longer works Logitech keyboard

Tags: keyboard, function-keys, logitech-keyboard

The calculator button on my Logitech keyboard stopped working suddenly. I would like to know what could have happened to it. It was working fine until about 3 days ago, then it would not open the calculator program.

What might have happened to my keyboard to cause it to no longer open the calculator program when I press the key?

Answer (score 3):

Mine did the same thing...then I did FN and toggled it with the calculator key. This popped up BING, so sticky key was out. Since I have a wireless keyboard I decided to remove the batteries and re-insert them. That worked and now it is properly functioning again.

Just a thought for someone else to try as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that I can think of in order from most likely to least:

1. Recent OS, software, or driver changes.
2. You may have toggled a function-lock key.
3. Your keyboard key is not mechanically working properly.

If you have updated your OS or keyboard software, you may have altered the functionality of your key mappings. You should check your Logitech keyboard software or driver. Roll back any recent OS changes or software changes. Update your keyboard driver or keyboard software.

Look on your keyboard for a Fn or function key, toggle it and test the calculator key again.

Remove your keycap from your keyboard and clean the contacts. I think most Logitech keyboards have rubber dome keys so it should be easy to clean. Here is a video but you can look around for more if this isn't close enough for your model keyboard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GAcBfuTDYs

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I just had this same problem.  There was no explanation for it.  I used the function key to try some of the other secondary key options, which worked fine, then the calculator suddenly decided to work again after that.  Strange, but worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a different option and then back to 'Open application' fixed the issue for me as well on Mac.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1105190)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and a Logitech Firmware Update fixed my problem...
I have the K540 and the Calculator button works like a charm.

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404523105175-MX-Keys-calculator-button-won-t-launch-the-calculator